# How can I send `Class<Item>` to the `ItemLiveData` class constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have this class:

```
class ItemLiveData<I>(private val classType: Class<I>): LiveData<I>() {
    //I need to use classType
}
```

And I have another class where I need to pass a custom class to constructor:

```
class MyRepository constructor() {
    override fun getLiveData(): ItemLiveData<Item> {
        return ItemLiveData(Class<Item>)
    }
}
```

And Android Studio is complaining with:

> Function invocation 'Class()' expected.

However, If I change:

```
return ItemLiveData(Class<Item>)
```

To:

```
return ItemLiveData(javaClass)
```

I get:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required: ItemLiveData<Item>
found: ItemLiveData<MyRepository>
```

How can I send `Class<Item>` to the `ItemLiveData` class constructor? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemLiveData(Class<Item>)` should be `ItemLiveData(Item::class.java)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me check and get back to you.